# How to execute script on schedule?

Tags: python, automation

I have two Python scripts on my machine that I want to execute two times a day on specific time period. How do I automate this task? Since I will be away from home and thus my computer for a while, I want to upload them to a site and  be executed from there automatic without me doing anything.

How can I do this?

Comment: What operating system are you running?

Comment: How about `cron`, if you are on a Linux or Mac machine?

Comment: cron for linux or mac, Windows task schedular for Windows

Comment: Mac os but I need some web based solution though since my computer will not be running 24/7

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can use `cron` for this if you are on a Linux machine. Cron is a system daemon used to execute specific tasks at specific times.

`cron` works on the principle of `crontab`, a text file with a list of commands to be run at specified times. It follows a specific format, which can is explained in detail in `man 5 crontab`

### Format for crontab

Each of the sections is separated by a space, with the final section having one or more spaces in it. No spaces are allowed within Sections 1-5, only between them. Sections 1-5 are used to indicate when and how often you want the task to be executed. This is how a cron job is laid out:

minute (0-59), hour (0-23, 0 = midnight), day (1-31), month (1-12), weekday (0-6, 0 = Sunday), command

`01 04 1 1 1 /usr/bin/somedirectory/somecommand`

The above example will run /usr/bin/somedirectory/somecommand at 4:01am on January 1st plus every Monday in January. An asterisk (*) can be used so that every instance (every hour, every weekday, every month, etc.) of a time period is used. Code:

`01 04 * * * /usr/bin/somedirectory/somecommand`

The above example will run /usr/bin/somedirectory/somecommand at 4:01am on every day of every month.

Comma-separated values can be used to run more than one instance of a particular command within a time period. Dash-separated values can be used to run a command continuously. Code:

`01,31 04,05 1-15 1,6 * /usr/bin/somedirectory/somecommand`

The above example will run `/usr/bin/somedirectory/somecommand` at 01 and 31 past the hours of 4:00am and 5:00am on the 1st through the 15th of every January and June.

The "/usr/bin/somedirectory/somecommand" text in the above examples indicates the task which will be run at the specified times. It is recommended that you use the full path to the desired commands as shown in the above examples. Enter *`which somecommand`* in the terminal to find the full path to *somecommand*. The crontab will begin running as soon as it is properly edited and saved.

You may want to run a script some number of times per time unit. For example if you want to run it every 10 minutes use the following crontab entry (runs on minutes divisible by 10: 0, 10, 20, 30, etc.)

`*/10 * * * * /usr/bin/somedirectory/somecommand`

which is also equivalent to the more cumbersome

`0,10,20,30,40,50 * * * * /usr/bin/somedirectory/somecommand`

Comment: Is there some kind of web-based solution out there? Since I will not leave my computer(laptop) running at home 24/7, I need a service that can provide me this solution.

Comment: @Zip We offer exactly that at [SeekWell](https://seekwell.io/?ref=so). You can schedule Jupyter Notebooks with Python from our [Chrome Extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/seekwell/mefkdbekccdbdihhondepjimindlbpfg) with just a couple clicks.

Comment: Buy a cheap PC and use it as a Linux server that can run these scripts as needed and run continuously. That way, you won't have to pay anyone else to run your stuff. There are a ton of people, including myself that use a Raspberry Pi for tasks such as this.

Answer (score 9):

In Windows I have come up with two solutions.

### First option: Create a .bat file.

**Step 1**

Create a .bat file to indicate the command you want to run and the script file that will be executed, for instance:

```
start C:\Users\userX\Python.exe C:\Users\userX\PycharmProjects\Automation_tasks\create_workbook.py
```

**Step 2**

Open the Task Scheduler and click on the Task Scheduler Library to see the current tasks that are executed. Click on the Create Task option.

[image: Main window Task Scheduler]

**Step 3**

In the General tab, put the name of your new task and click on the option `Run whether user is logged on or not`, check the option `Run with highest privileges` and make sure to setup the appropriate version of you OS (in my case I picked `Windows 7, Windows Server 2008 R2`.

[image: High privileges]

**Step 4**

In the Actions tab, click on the New button and type in the following:

In **Program/Scripts** you need to look up for the Powershell path that the Task Scheduler will invoke to run the .bat file. In my case, my Powershell path was:
`C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe`

In **Add arguments (optional)** you need to type the path of the file that will be executed by Powershell. In my case, the path was:

`C:\Users\userX\Desktop\run_the_bat_file.bat`

In **Start in (optional)** you need to type the path of the file but without the name of the .bat file, that is:

`C:\Users\userX\Desktop\`

[image: Configure the settings for Powershell]

**Step 5**

Click on the Triggers tab and select how often you want to execute this task.

[image: Frequency of the task to be executed]

**Step 6**

Lastly, test your task to see if it truly works by selecting it from the Task Scheduler Library and doing click on the Run option.

[image: Test your task]

### Second option: Run the .py file with the Task Scheduler

**Step 1**

Open the Task Scheduler and click on the Task Scheduler Library to see the current tasks that are executed. Click on the Create Task option.

[image: Main window Task Scheduler]

**Step 2**

In the General tab, put the name of your new task and click on the option `Run whether user is logged on or not`, check the option `Run with highest privileges` and make sure to setup the appropriate version of you OS (in my case I picked `Windows 7, Windows Server 2008 R2`.

[image: High privileges]

**Step 3**

In the Actions tab, click on the New button and type in the following:

In **Program/Scripts** you need to look up for the Python.exe path that the Task Scheduler will invoke to run the python script. In my case, my Python.exe path was:
`C:\Users\userX\python.exe`

In **Add arguments (optional)** you need to **only** type the name of your python script. In my case, the path was:

`Permissions_dump.py`

In **Start in (optional)** you need to type the path of the file but without the name of the python script, that is:

`C:\Users\userX\PycharmProjects\1099_vendors_costs`

[image: Python configuration]

**Step 4**

Click on the Triggers tab and select how often you want to execute this task.

[image: Frequency of the task to be executed]

**Step 5**

Lastly, test your task to see if it truly works by selecting it from the Task Scheduler Library and doing click on the Run option.

[image: Test your task]

### Another option (in case you convert a .py to a .exe)

If you use the library Cx_Freeze to convert a .py to a .exe and you want to use the task scheduler to automate this task then you need to follow these steps:

**Step 1**

Click on Create Task and then click on the Actions tab to type in the following:

In **Program/Scripts** you need to look up for the `C:\Windows\explorer.exe` path that the Task Scheduler will invoke to run the .exe script.

In **Add arguments (optional)** you need to **only** type the name of your .exe file: `CustomerPopulation.exe`

In **Start in (optional)** you need to type the path of the file but without the name of the .exe file, that is:

`C:\Users\userX\PycharmProjects\executables`

[image: exe parameters]

In the General tab, make sure to have selected the `Run only when user is logged on` and have unchecked the `Run with the highest privileges`.

**If reports stopped working**
Make sure to check if your password hasn’t expired, otherwise the reports won’t be sent.

References:

1. https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/140110/running-python-script-in-task-scheduler-script-will-not-run?newreg=603bcdbc381b41a283e5d8d0561b835e
2. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oJ4nktysxnE
3. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n2Cr_YRQk7o

Comment: Please explain how to do that in the answer itself.

Comment: @BaummitAugen I have added further explanations about how to run automated tasks with Python. Feel free to improve them.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using OSX then [launchd](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/launchd.8.html) is the preferred way to schedule tasks. There is a OSX CLI for launchd called [launchctl](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/launchctl.1.html#//apple_ref/doc/man/1/launchctl) but if you prefer a GUI my preferred one is [launchcontrol](http://www.soma-zone.com/LaunchControl/).