# How to Export Number of Followers from Instagram accounts to Googlesheet?

Tags: google-sheets, instagram, instagram-api

I manage different Instagram accounts, some of them are private and others are business accounts. Instead of checking all of them daily, I need to list them in one Google sheet and see the number of their followers.
Previously,  I have used XML to fetch that. But now it is not working. Is there any way for doing this? (Also, I need this data to be updated automatically without the needs to run a code each time so other team members can see the data whenever required)

My previous sheet was this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/swL4e.png)

Answer (score 0):

You should use instagram api if you wanna extract your  own followers
First connect your instagram account to the api
And then you have followers list
Second write a loop statement and write the list one by one to a excel file  by the way you can use free excel package for python

Comment: I need this data to be automatically updated. Can I do that with method? Or every time I need to run the code?

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do, i think you can use of InstaPy bot which has written by python. When you start this bot and give it some accounts, it collect all information about these accounts and save them in CSV file. It is simple and you can install it on Windows, Linux or even MacOs
https://pypi.org/project/instapy

Comment: I need this data to be updated automatically. Can I do that with method? Or every time I need to run the code?

Comment: In terms of automatic updating, there are many ways like schedule your code to run. In Linux you can use Corn https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30835547/how-to-execute-python-script-on-schedule

Comment: Check this out: https://instapy.org/relationship-tools