# How to schedule full refresh scripts to run during weekends?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have my python scripts which execute every weekday and refreshes tableau datasets. This is all being done incremental refresh on a daily basis.

Now, during weekends instead of manual refresh, I want these scripts to run with a full refresh. Any ideas on how we can achieve this?

Example:

I have tasks in my script like

```
#Run Tasks

refresh_tableA()
refresh_tableB()
refresh_tableC()
refresh_tablemain(i)
refresh_tableD()
```

Where the `refresh_maintable()` is an incremental refresh. Want that to trigger to a full refresh on weekends.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to execute python script on schedule?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30835547/how-to-execute-python-script-on-schedule)

Answer (score 0):

You need to have two [cron](https://opensource.com/article/17/11/how-use-cron-linux) entries.

1. [week days](https://crontab.guru/every-weekday) only - call the python code and order it to create partial refresh
2. [wekends](https://crontab.guru/every-weekend) - call the python code and order it to create full refresh

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is a scheduler.
You have 2 options here either use Task Scheduler/Cronjob (Based on your OS) or using python library for this.

I think there is library for cronjob in python `pycron`.

That way you can schedule you scripts easily. let me know if you still dont understand the flow or want code. Most probably you'll find something on github.