# How to execute script on schedule on WIndows?

Tags: automation, scripting, airflow, schedule

I use Jupyter Notebook on Windows. I have several Python scripts. I want to execute it two times a day, once a week and so on. How do I automate this task?

This question is for Linux [How to execute script on schedule?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30835547/how-to-execute-script-on-schedule)

I get 'Windows cannot open this type of file (.ipynb)' when i try to use library schedule

I tried using other libraries, but they are suitable for Linux, not Windows

This is example:

```
def func(file_location):
    os.system(file_location)

file_location = 'path'
schedule.every(100).seconds.do(func(file_location))
```